# Select query from view in Unidata

Tags: sql, unidata

I want to perform the below SQL in Unidata

```
Select tab.col1, tab.col2 from (select col1, col2 from table1) tab;
```

Please help me for Unidata database

Comment: Is this from within Unidata, or externally via ODBC?

Comment: Just to confirm - this question is for https://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-unidata, not https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/ ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bit redundant with the second select (select col1, col2 from table1).

Unidata would be:

LIST table1 col1 col2

-Arthur

Comment: Good point - the sql would seem equivalent to "Select tab.col1, tab.col2 from table1 tab;"

Comment: This is just an example. Actual SQL is much more complex for which this feature is absolutely necessary. Please let me know if there is any such feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native SQL interface to Unidata, but it's possible to run SQL against a Unidata database from Windows by setting up an ODBC datasource. It's not trivial and will take some work to do. If you go to the Rocket website and search for documentation, you'll end up here:

https://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-u2/documentation

And from there you'll want to drill down to "U2 Clients and APIs/Rocket U2 Clients and APIs U2 ODBC Developer Guide". Again, if this is not already setup for your environment, it's quite a bit of work to get going. If you can run native Unidata queries, that will be significantly easier. Look at the Uniquery reference manual for that.